# control the order of ajax calls in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have code that look like so

```
var response = [];
requests.forEach(function(request){
    $.when(
           doFirstThing();       //makes ajax call and is async
    ).then(
           doSecondThing();      //makes ajax call and pushes its results to response
    );
}
```

When I get the responses back and pushed, they are in different order and I was wondering how I can get them in the correct order in which they were called by the loop.

I tried just sorting the response array outside the forEach loop but that did not work. Also tried adding

```
.done(
    sortResponses();
);
```

but that did not either. Please help.

Comment: collect promises in your response array, and then apply them to $.when. .then on the result of that would have the results in order.

Comment: @KevinB is there a more in depth example of that?

Comment: As a matter of fact, [there is!](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: That will execute them in order, but with data needed from the response of the first, if that is what you are trying to do

Comment: yes, but also I need the first loop to push the results of doSecondThing() to response BEFORE the second loop and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `.then()` and `.done()` must be a reference to a function. You're calling the function immediately because you put `()` after the function name. Either pass the function name by itself

```
.then(doSecondThing)
```

or use an anonymous function to call it

```
.then(() => doSecondThing())
```

Comment: wrapping that in an anonymous function might be easier to understand, passing functions as arguments can be confusing at first

Comment: @CoryDanielson I've added that variation.

Comment: if I use anonymous functions can I also pass parameters into the functions that I actually want to use? like function(){ doFirstThing(data); } ?

Comment: Yes, of course. The anonymous function can do anything it wants.